# Unity Camera Focus OnColliderEnter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

when the player touches an object, I want it to concentrate the focus on another gameobject. How do I write this to the script?

Comment: Have you tried writing any code at all to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Try inserting the camera into the object you want it to focus on

Example: "camera.Parent = object;"

You could also put the camera in a object and just position the object on the object[2] you want to focus on. When you want to change focus you could tween the position of the object to the other object[2].